# Removing dicts with duplicate value from list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts as follows:

```
[{'ppm_error': -5.441115144810845e-07, 'key': 'Y7', 'obs_ion': 1054.5045550349998},
{'ppm_error': 2.3119997582222951e-07, 'key': 'Y9', 'obs_ion': 1047.547178035},
{'ppm_error': 2.3119997582222951e-07, 'key': 'Y9', 'obs_ion': 1381.24928035},
{'ppm_error': -2.5532659838679713e-06, 'key': 'Y4', 'obs_ion': 741.339467035},
{'ppm_error': 1.3036219678359603e-05, 'key': 'Y10', 'obs_ion': 1349.712302035},
{'ppm_error': 3.4259216556970878e-06, 'key': 'Y6', 'obs_ion': 941.424286035},
{'ppm_error': 1.1292770047090912e-06, 'key': 'Y2', 'obs_ion': 261.156025035},
{'ppm_error': 1.1292770047090912e-06, 'key': 'Y2', 'obs_ion': 389.156424565},
{'ppm_error': 9.326980606898406e-06, 'key': 'Y5', 'obs_ion': 667.3107950350001}
]
```

I want to remove dicts with duplicate keys such that only dicts with unique 'key' remain. It doesn't matter which dict ends up in the final list. So the final list should look as follows:

```
[{'ppm_error': -5.441115144810845e-07, 'key': 'Y7', 'obs_ion': 1054.5045550349998},
{'ppm_error': 2.3119997582222951e-07, 'key': 'Y9', 'obs_ion': 1381.24928035},
{'ppm_error': -2.5532659838679713e-06, 'key': 'Y4', 'obs_ion': 741.339467035},
{'ppm_error': 1.3036219678359603e-05, 'key': 'Y10', 'obs_ion': 1349.712302035},
{'ppm_error': 3.4259216556970878e-06, 'key': 'Y6', 'obs_ion': 941.424286035},
{'ppm_error': 1.1292770047090912e-06, 'key': 'Y2', 'obs_ion': 261.156025035},
{'ppm_error': 9.326980606898406e-06, 'key': 'Y5', 'obs_ion': 667.3107950350001}
]
```

Is it possible to use itertools.groupby function for doing this or is there another way of approaching this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say `keys`, you mean `key`, right?

Comment: Also, does the order of dictionaries matter in the output list?

Comment: No. it doesn't matter what order they appear in.

Comment: Cool, I have given both the versions in my answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the order matters, then you can use  [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to collect all the items, like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print OrderedDict((d["key"], d) for d in my_list).values()
```

And if the order doesn't matter, you can use a normal dictionary, like this

```
print {d["key"]:d for d in my_list}.values()
```

Comment: Best solution, as key has that magic property of having unique keys :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to remember processed keys and return different result if key has already been seen. This can be done using memoization:

```py
def get_key_watcher():
    keys_seen = set()
    def key_not_seen(d):
        key = d['key']
        if key in keys_seen:
            return False  # key is not new
        else:
            keys_seen.add(key)
            return True  # key seen for the first time
    return key_not_seen
```

Then you could use it like this:

```py
>>> filtered_dicts = filter(get_key_watcher(), dicts)
>>> filtered_dicts
[{'ppm_error': -5.441115144810845e-07, 'obs_ion': 1054.5045550349998, 'key': 'Y7'},
 {'ppm_error': 2.3119997582222951e-07, 'obs_ion': 1047.547178035, 'key': 'Y9'},
 {'ppm_error': -2.5532659838679713e-06, 'obs_ion': 741.339467035, 'key': 'Y4'},
 {'ppm_error': 1.3036219678359603e-05, 'obs_ion': 1349.712302035, 'key': 'Y10'},
 {'ppm_error': 3.4259216556970878e-06, 'obs_ion': 941.424286035, 'key': 'Y6'},
 {'ppm_error': 1.1292770047090912e-06, 'obs_ion': 261.156025035, 'key': 'Y2'},
 {'ppm_error': 9.326980606898406e-06, 'obs_ion': 667.3107950350001, 'key': 'Y5'}]
```

It maintains order of dictionaries, obviously. And keeps the dictionary encountered first.

Comment: Really elegant, I was groping around with search terms like 'filter', and here's a great example of exactly what I was looking for. Just another reminder that python looks an awful lot like pseudocode, which I guess is the definition of intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
list = [...] # your list

finallist = dict(map(lambda x: (x['key'],x), list)).values()
```

Basically its the same solution @thefourtheye provides in his answer...

Comment: Could you add a description? Currently this answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

convert it to a numpy array

```
a = numpy.array([(d["ppm_error"],d["key"],d["obs_ion"]) for d in my_dicts])
mask =numpy.unique(a[:,1],True)[1]
uniques = a[mask]
```

then back to a dict

```
unique_entries = map(dict,[zip(labels,row) for row in uniques])
```