# Remove dicts with duplicate value from list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Similar to [Removing dicts with duplicate value from list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875991/removing-dicts-with-duplicate-value-from-list-of-dicts-python), but seeking understanding not just an answer.

I am confronted with a result that exposes a fundamental gap in my understanding of lists, loops, or the `list.remove()` function.  Perhaps an explanation would be helpful to others facing the same question:

```
>>> my_dict_list = [
    {'a': 50, 'b': 4000},
    {'a': 4000, 'b': 4000},
    {'a': 5000, 'b': 5000},
    {'a': 501, 'b': 501},
    {'a': 400, 'b': 100},
    {'a': 4000, 'b': 4000},
    {'a': 5000, 'b': 5000},
]
```

Resulting confusion using a simple loop to remove dicts where 'a' and 'b' values are equal:

```
>>> for d in my_dict_list:
...     if d['a'] == d['b']:
...         my_dict_list.remove(d)
...         
>>> my_dict_list
[{'a': 50, 'b': 4000}, {'a': 5000, 'b': 5000}, {'a': 400, 'b': 100}, {'a': 5000, 'b': 5000}]
```

Not understanding the above is leaving a gaping wound in my soul. Some were removed, others were not.

BTW: this easily gets the correct result:

```
>>> [d for d in my_dict_list if d['a'] != d['b']]
[{'a': 50, 'b': 4000}, {'a': 400, 'b': 100}]
```

Comment: Modifying an iterable as you iterate over it will usually result in bugs.  Don't do it!  The second form you did is the preferred way.

Comment: https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/

Comment: also here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127618/modifying-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-with-python